# Content of a Pane extend borderpane

Tags: java, javafx

So this is maybe just confusion, but I have a BorderPane with a Pane in the Center. This Pane contains some imageViews which are animated (Timeline & Translate) and move in and out of the Size of the BorderPane Center.

If a ImageView moves in from the right, it overlaps the BorderPane Left. Why is this happening? Isn't a Pane supposed to have at maximum the size of its parent?

Thx in advance

Comment: `BorderPane` doesn't clip the content of the regions. If you want to ensure the left region appears over the top of the center region, call `setLeft()` *after* you call `setCenter()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I give you a thumbs up somehow?
Is there a resource (book, website) where I can find more info on this?

Comment: Information on how BorderPane works, including that it does not clip children, is in the [BorderPane javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html).

Comment: Oh man, that's obvious. sry